# Different fields in user profile for different user roles

Tags: entities, users

I have created user roles parent, teacher and student. I want to relate parents with a student by creating a `Field` **Related student** for only parents. I tried using **User References**. But that makes the field common for all user roles. I also tried **Profile2** module. But that doesnot exactly fit what I want. Is there any other way to achieve that ? Any suggestions please. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) will let you assign different permissions to a field based on role.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.
>
> #### Features
>
> - Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes
> - Role-based field permissions allowing different viewing patterned based on what access the user has
> - Author-level permissions allow viewing and editing of fields based on who the entity owner is
> - Permissions for each field are not enabled by default. Instead, administrators can enable these permissions explicitly for the fields where this feature is needed

Answer (score 0):

Use Profile2, and you can have whole sets of fields only used by the role chosen. If not, see below.

This is the best option and I'll explain:

If you have fields, and use field permissions. Say you have employee # and customer number and both are required. Field permissions allows administrators to edit all values on these fields. /sarcasm Well sorry, you can't create your user because you haven't filled in all required fields /sarcasm. So you either have to enter a phony employee number or a phony customer number depending on who you are creating.

Other option: don't have required fields, instead use complete_profile to simulate required fields.